# Want to hide the parent div if empty

Tags: php, jquery

I´ve tried to build a sales counter for my woo-shop that will be placed on the product page.
But I can not hide it when the count is empty or 0.

I want the around-circle div to hide when strong is empty or have a value of 0.

```
<div class="around-circle">
        <div class="second circle">
            <strong></strong>
        </div>
        <span><b>Kunder</b> har nyligen köpt den här produkten</span>
</div>
```

```
(function($) { 
      $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
        value: 1,
        size: 35,
        thickness: 5,
        fill: "#fff",
        animation: { duration: 4000, swing: "circleProgressEasing" }
      }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
        $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(0 * progress));
      });
      $('.around-circle').delay(5000).fadeOut();    
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you mean empty or emty?

Answer (score 0):

easy workflow

```js
let element=document.querySelector('#divId');
let parent=element.parentNode;

if(parent.innerHtml==''){

   parent.remove();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it to work. But I think it will be some kind of problem because the number in the strong-tag start at 0 and then adding during an animation. So even if number is 10 it starts from 0. Check this please and you will understand. https://jsfiddle.net/PaerPaer/a9xbfy28/4/ maby there is a better way to build this function. Thanks!

Comment: you can directly use ``` .around-circle ``` for selector on your link, do you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

you can use some function like this:

```
<?Php

if(!$result){ ?>
<script>document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; </script>
<?php

}
?>
```